# Access denied error when using Document Sets and 'Send to' Connection

Tags: document-set, records-center, send-to-destination

I have set up the "Send to" connection in Central Admin and this works fine when I am sending documents.

However, when I try to send a Document Set (with contribute permissions), it will show an Access Denied error. The Document Set will actually reach target library, but the error displays, which will be confusing for the end-user. The link stub which is left in the initial library also has a 403 error when clicked on.

Interestingly, when I try to send a Document Set from initial library to target library with Site Collection Administrator permissions, it all works fine.

What do I need to do to ensure Contributors can send Document Sets to my target library?

Comment: Can you confirm the total size of the document set is less than 50 MB?

Comment: Confirmed. The document sets only have one document inside for testing.

Comment: Thanks. Please examine the full URL of AccessDenied.aspx page user sees (might be useful to open the doc in separate browser tab first), and also check if ULS log contains any related entries.

Comment: This is the URL when Access Denied error shows: https://nestapps/functions/000/000.01/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx
All domain users have read and contribute permissions for https://nestapps/functions/000/000.01/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this on my own because I'm an absolute G. Answer:

I created a new permissions level by copying the default Contribute permissions level but also included 'Manage Web Site' (and by association 'Add and customize pages') to this. This then enabled contributors to send Document Sets to the target. However, it meant that they had elevated SCA permissions for the whole site. So I broke site inheritance and gave this new Contribute + Manage Web Site permission level **only** at library level. This ensured there was no additional site functionality given, but Document Sets could still be sent.

Someone hi-5 me.